# Wave Equation Via d'Alambert

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, chain-rule, wave-equation

> $$u_{tt} = 4u_{xx},\ u(x,\ 0) = \sin(\pi x),\ u_t (x,\ 0) = 0.$$

I factored the differential operators and used undetermined coefficients (can go into more detail on this part but I think it matters not) to find the general solution $$u = h(2t + x) + g(2t - x)$$ for arbitrary functions $h$ and $g$.  Applying the initial conditions yields $$\begin{cases}\sin(\pi x) = h(x) + g(-x) \\ 0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}[h(2t + x) + g(2t - x)]_{t = 0}\end{cases}$$ which will require the second equation to be antidifferentiated with respect to $t$ in order for the system to be solved simultaneously. Thus, I end up with $$\begin{cases}\sin(\pi x) = h(x) + g(-x) \\ f(x) = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial t}[h(2t + x) + g(2t - x)]_{t = 0}\,\mathrm dt\end{cases}$$ for an arbitrary function $f$. I'm not really sure how to finish solving this.

I could make the substitutions $y = 2t + x$ and $z = 2t - x$, leading to $$f(x) = 2 \int \left[\frac{\partial h(y)}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial g(z)}{\partial z}\right]_{t = 0}\,\mathrm dt,$$ but other than getting the $2$ from the chain rule derivatives pulled out, I'm not sure how to continue. I don't think I can just cancel the partial differentiation with the antidifferentiation, because of the $t = 0$ evaluation operation. How can I finish solving these equations?

Answer (score 1):

$\def\g{\widetilde{g}}$One of the boundary condition, i.e.$$
\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(h(x + 2t) + g(-x + 2t)) \right|_{t = 0} = 0,
$$
can be simplified as $h'(x) + g'(-x) \equiv 0$ by the chain rule. Thus$$
\begin{cases}
h(x) + g(-x) = \sin(πx)\\
h'(x) + g'(-x) = 0
\end{cases}.
$$
Defining $\g(x) = g(-x)$, the above equations become$$
\begin{cases}
h(x) + \g(x) = \sin(πx)\\
h'(x) - \g'(x) = 0
\end{cases},
$$
where the second equation implies that $\g(x) = h(x) + c$ for some constant $c$, and plugging into the first equation shows that$$
h(x) = \frac{1}{2} \sin(πx) + C_0,\quad \g(x) = \frac{1}{2} \sin(πx) - C_0,
$$
where $C_0 = -\dfrac{c}{2}$ is a constant. Thus$$
h(x) = \frac{1}{2} \sin(πx) + C_0,\quad g(x) = -\frac{1}{2} \sin(πx) - C_0.
$$

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your very first simplification using the chain rule, and the ambiguity of $'$ derivative notation.  Applying the chain rule, I get $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(h(x + 2t) + g(-x + 2t))|_{t = 0} = 0 \implies \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(h(y) + g(z))|_{t = 0} = 0$ (where $y = x + 2t$ and $z = -x + 2t$) $\implies (2\frac{dh(y)}{dy} + 2\frac{dg(z)}{dz})|_{t = 0} = 0 \implies (\frac{dh(y)}{dy} + \frac{dg(z)}{dz})|_{t = 0} = 0$ or $(\frac{\partial h(x + 2t)}{\partial (x + 2t)} + \frac{\partial g(-x + 2t)}{\partial (-x + 2t)})|_{t = 0} = 0$.

Comment: Are you plugging $t = 0$ into the differentials at this point to get $\frac{\partial h(x)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial g(-x)}{\partial (-x)} = 0$, or else how are you proceeding?  It seems like plugging in $t = 0$ at this point before resolving the differentiation would be illegal.

Comment: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(h(x+2t))=h'(x+2t)·\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(x+2t)=2h'(x+2t).$$Btw, the notation $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial(x+2t)}$ isn't standard as far as I know.

Comment: Hmm, I just don't understand how we can plug $0$ in for $t$ before fully completing the differentiation.  I think the $'$ notation is misleading me in some way.

Comment: @user10478 To be more precise, defining $y(x,t)=x+2t$, the chain rule is exactly laid out as$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(h(y(x,t)))\right|_{x=x_0,t=0}=h'(y(x_0,0))·\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(x_0,0)=2h'(x_0)$$for any $x_0\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Okay, last question I think.  What did you antidifferentiate with respect to in order to move from $h'(x) - g'(x) = 0$ to $g(x) = h(x) + c$?  The only thing that remotely makes sense to me is antidifferentiating with respect to $t$, but then it should be $g(x) = h(x) + f(x)$ for an arbitrary function $f$?

Comment: @user10478$$(h-g)'=h'-g'=0\Longrightarrow h-g=\text{constant}.$$